# Copies of same web-part do not function

Tags: list, web-part, sharepoint-addin, attachments

firstly I have an image for clarity sake

[image: <img> https://i.gyazo.com/df2287a3c8be87aae59e9f4ae02d5d57.png </img>]

It is pulling names (blocked out) from a list and displaying all of the attached images associated with them nearby

My issue is that if a second or third copy of this web part is added, it will not even begin to load. I have tried pointing the copies to extract data from the same list and I have tried pointing them all to separate lists

I have no idea why this might be the case. Even the smallest clue is a great help. Thank you!

Comment: is that a custom web part?

Comment: Yes it is, i should have added that.